# Add output of for loop to list

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have looked at previously asked question about keeping 'for loop' output in a list but I can't seem to apply it to my function.

Maybe someone can give my a clue about what I am doing wrong.

```
dna_seqs <- list('id1', 'ATGGCAATAACCCCCCGTTTCTACTTCTAGAGGAGAAAAGT', 'id2', 'TCCGTTAAGATATTCTTACGTGTGACGTAGCTATGTATTTTGCAGAGCTGGCGAACGCGTTGAACACTTCACAGATGGT', 'id3', 'AGCTGGTTCCTGCGTGAGCTCGAGACTCGGGATGACAGCTCTTTAAACATAGAGCGGGGGCGTCGAACGGTCGA', 'id4', 'CATCACCGCGATAGGCTGACAAAGGTTTAACATTGAATAGCAAGGCACTTCCGGTCTCAATGAACGGCCGGGAA')

gc_list <- list() 
count_gc <- function(x) {
  for (i in x) {
    if (startsWith(i, 'id')) {
      gc_list[[i]] <- i

    } 
    else {
      seq <- str_to_upper(i)
      seq <- gsub('N', '', seq)
      gc <- str_count(seq, 'G') + str_count(seq, 'C')
      gc_content <- gc / nchar(seq) * 100
      gc_list[[i]] <- gc_content
    }
  } 
}
```

This function is not appending any elements to the list, which is still empty ?

Comment: You should not use a static object from the global environment within a custom function. Instead, use a variable and return it within the function call: `count_gc <- function(x)...`. Replace the `gc_list[[i]]` with `mylist[[i]]` within the function, place a `mylist <- list()` at the beginning and a `return(mylist)` at the end, then call it with `gc_list <- count_gc(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lapply()` and save yourself the worry

```
gc_list <- lapply(dna_seqs, function(seq) {
    if (startsWith(seq, "id")) {
        seq
    } else {
        seq <- str_to_upper(seq)
        seq <- gsub('N', '', seq)
        gc <- str_count(seq, 'G') + str_count(seq, 'C')
        gc / nchar(seq) * 100
    }
})
```

But better, use a 'tidy' data structure

```
df = data.frame(
    id = unlist(dna_seqs[c(TRUE, FALSE)]),
    seq = unlist(dna_seqs[c(FALSE, TRUE)]),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

and a simpler (no `if ()` condition) and vectorized (`x` can be any length) function

```
gc_content = function(x) {
    x = gsub("N", "", str_to_upper(x))
    str_count(x, "[GC]") / nchar(x) * 100
}
```

to mutate the tidy data

```
df$gc = gc_content(df$seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code

```
for(i in 1:length(dna_seqs)){

  if (startsWith(dna_seqs[[i]], 'id')) {
    gc_list[[i]] <- dna_seqs[[i]]

  } 
  else {
    seq <- str_to_upper(dna_seqs[[i]])
    seq <- gsub('N', '', seq)
    gc <- str_count(seq, 'G') + str_count(seq, 'C')
    gc_content <- gc / nchar(seq) * 100
    gc_list[[i]] <- gc_content
  }
}
```